# Multi-Touch tutorial, stuck on unknown variable

Tags: android, zooming

I am trying to implement this multi-touch android tutorial

http://www.zdnet.com/blog/burnette/how-to-use-multi-touch-in-android-2-part-5-implementing-the-drag-gesture/1789?tag=mantle_skin;content

I am stuck in Step 5 for the implementation, what is the start variable?

```
  switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
   case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
      savedMatrix.set(matrix);
      start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
      Log.d(TAG, "mode=DRAG" );
      mode = DRAG;
      break;
   case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
   case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
      mode = NONE;
      Log.d(TAG, "mode=NONE" );
      break;
   case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
      if (mode == DRAG) {
         matrix.set(savedMatrix);
         matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x,
         event.getY() - start.y);
      }
      break;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download the complete source [here](http://pragprog.com/titles/eband3/source_code).
The start variable is of type PointF, it represents the starting point of the gesture.